# java Restful web service get the data from textbox in POST action

Tags: java, web-services, rest, post

I am new to Restful web service in java and this is my first web application, I searched a lot but everybody asking more complicated question than what I need.

I have a pretty simple html with a textbox and a submit button. Also I have a POST function in my web service as below:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})       
public Response showSearchResult(String incomingData) throws Exception {                
    String query = incomingData;
    RepositoryMongo repository = new RepositoryMongo("InvertedIndex", "InvertedIndex", "documents");
    InvertedIndex invertedIndex = new InvertedIndex(repository);
    ArrayList<Posting> result = invertedIndex.processQuery_Posting_Based(query, 10,"1");
    String htmlResult = invertedIndex.getHTMLResult(result);
    return Response.ok(htmlResult).build();
}
```

The problem is that my incomingData = "query_input=canada+singer&search=search", while I want it to be the content of the textbox only. I can parse the string that I am receiving, but is that way correct? Is there any way that I can get "canada singer" as input directly? how can I control input type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@FormParam` annotation for a POST request, or the `@PathParam` annotation for a GET request.  These go on parameters to your method, to indicate that the values for the parameters should be pulled out of either the URL (for a GET) or the posted body (for a POST).

Have a look at section 7.3 of http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html where there is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

For this result - “query_input=canada+singer" ,you can get the url value with `@QueryParam("query_input")`.

Alternatively,
We can even implement this using this @Context UriInfo

getQueryParameters() method has getFirst - in which you include the argument to fetch,just like below

```
String query_input_value= url.getQueryParameters().getFirst("query_input");
```

Try this :

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})       
public Response showSearchResult(@Context UriInfo url) throws Exception {  

String query_input_value= url.getQueryParameters().getFirst("query_input");              
    String query = incomingData;
    RepositoryMongo repository = new RepositoryMongo("InvertedIndex", "InvertedIndex", "documents");
    InvertedIndex invertedIndex = new InvertedIndex(repository);
    ArrayList<Posting> result = invertedIndex.processQuery_Posting_Based(query, 10,"1");
    String htmlResult = invertedIndex.getHTMLResult(result);
    return Response.ok(htmlResult).build();
}
```

Comment: url.getQueryParameters() was null.